# Extended real line sigma algebra

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, borel-sets

Like in Folland, if we define:
$\mathscr{B}_{\overline{\mathbb{R}}} = \{E \subset \overline{\mathbb{R}}: E \cap \mathbb{R}\in \mathscr{B}_{\mathbb{R}} \}$. How do we prove $\mathscr{B}_{\overline{\mathbb{R}}}= \sigma(\mathscr{C})$ where $\mathscr{C} = \{(\alpha, \infty] ; \alpha \in \mathbb{R}\}$ directly?

We didn't define topology in $\mathscr{B}_{\overline{\mathbb{R}}}$.

Comment: $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is a metric space with $d(x,y)=|\arctan x-\arctan y|$; the topology on $\mathbb{R}$ as a subspace of $(\mathbb{R},d)$ coincidedswith the usual topology. Check that the Borel sets of $\mathbb{R}$ are are the same as the Borel sets of $\mathbb{R}$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$. In fact the Borel sets in $\overline{R}$ are of the form $A\cup B$ where $A$ is a Borel set in $\mathbb{R}$ (as you know it) and $B\subset\{-\infty,\infty\}$

Comment: @OliverDíaz what if we don't use any topology on the extended R?

Comment: To talk about Borel sets, you need a topology as that is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by open sets. To generate a topology, you can use the two point compactification: define open neighborhoods of $\infty$ as sets of the form $(a,\infty)\cup\{\infty\}$ and something similar for open neighborhoods of $-\infty$.  Chech that is a topology, that $\mathbb{R}$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ gets the same topology as before and the rest is as in my comment above.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a general trick to show equality of certain structures. It works for $\sigma$-algebras, topologies, subgroups of a given group, etc.

The idea is that you take a generating set $G_A, G_B$ of each object $A$ and $B$, and show that every element of the generating set $G_A$ is generated by $G_B$ and vice versa. This way you are essentially proving that the object generated by $G_A$ is contained in the object generated by $G_B$ and vice versa, making those generated objects equal. But those generated objects are exactly $A$ and $B$, making those equal.

In this case, $\sigma(\mathcal C)$ is by definition generated by $\mathcal C$. And $\mathcal B_{\overline{\mathbb R}}$ is generated by itself (I assume it is known that $\mathcal B_{\overline{\mathbb R}}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra). So we need to show that:

- every element of $\mathcal C$ is generated by elements of $\mathcal B_{\overline{\mathbb R}}$, and
- every element of $\mathcal B_{\overline{\mathbb R}}$ is generated by elements of $\mathcal C$

**$\mathcal C$ generated by $\mathcal B_{\overline{\mathbb R}}$:**

This is easy: It's trivially true since $\mathcal C\subset\mathcal B_{\overline{\mathbb R}}$. This is because $(\alpha,\infty]\cap\mathbb R=(\alpha,\infty)\in\mathcal B_{\mathbb R}$.

**$\mathcal B_{\overline{\mathbb R}}$ generated by $\mathcal C$**

We can generate every open subset of $\mathbb R$. To prove this, it suffices to show that we can generate $(a,b)$ for all $a,b\in\mathbb R$, because every open subset of $\mathbb R$ is a countable union of such intervals.

We have :

- $(a,\infty]\in\mathcal C$ by definition
- $[-\infty,b)=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty [-\infty,b-\frac1n]=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty(b-\frac1n,\infty]^c$
- $(a,b)=(a,\infty]\cap[-\infty,b)$

Now since we can generate every open subset of $\mathbb R$, we can also generate every element of $\mathcal B_{\mathbb R}$, since this is by definition generated by these open sets. And the elements of $\mathcal B_{\overline{\mathbb R}}$ are exactly those of $\mathcal B_{\mathbb R}$, but possibly also containing $-\infty,\infty$ or both. So if we can generate $\{\infty\}$ and $\{-\infty\}$, we are done. This is how we get those singletons:

- $\{\infty\}=\bigcap_{n=0}^\infty(n,\infty]$
- $\{-\infty\}=\bigcap_{n=0}^\infty[-\infty,-n]=\bigcap_{n=0}^\infty(-n,\infty]^c$

Comment: When you say "generate", (a,b) generate something outside of $\mathbb R$, because they now lie in $\overline{\mathbb R}$

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say. They generate many sets, some of which are open subsets of $\mathbb R$.